# Enable WS-Addressing in Mulesoft Web service consumer

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

How to enable WS-Addressing in Web service Consumer of Mulesoft.

When I search for WS-Addressing in mulesoft. It points to CXF. However the docs point that it's recommended to use web service consumer rather than CXF.

So is there any way to enable WS-Addressing. SoapAction is added into the WSDL

```
POST /esi2/esi-gateway/v2/common/v1 HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: "http://www.macquarie.com/...."
Host: www.macquarie.com
User-Agent: AHC/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1453

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-2004
```

...................

When Tested in SOAP UI I can find WS-A with all the details filled. How can i get a similar stuff in Mulesoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note :- This is the official answer. And it works. Fix the dummy web address in TO, Action and messageID.

Please add the following before webservice consumer . you should be set to go

```
<set-property propertyName="soap.to" value="&lt;wsa:To xmlns:wsa=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing&quot;&gt;http://www.asdfadsf.com/esi/common/v1&lt;/wsa:To&gt;" doc:name="Soap.To"/>

<set-property propertyName="soap.Action" value="&lt;wsa:Action xmlns:wsa=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing&quot;&gt;http://www.xyzdadadf.com/esi/common/1.0/getAuthenticationExpiryRequest&lt;/wsa:Action&gt;" doc:name="soap.action"/>

<set-property propertyName="soap.messageID" value="&lt;wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing&quot;&gt;urn:entity-name:version:1&lt;/wsa:MessageID&gt;" doc:name="soap.messageID"/>
```

I post this in the form for larger community help.